# JQuery not able to prevent event bubbling

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, droppable

I am trying to highlight element over droppable. The list has child and parent type element and i have put appropriate classes as well. Things are find but i am not able to prevent event bubbling. i have tried below code but not working somehow. While draggable is dragged over the droppable, all element (with parent class) starts flickering the yellow background. i have no idea how to stop this. i have tried stopPropagation(),stopImmediatePropagation() in over function but nothing worked out. my code is as below,

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
#NodeDetails {
    border: solid 1px red;  
    width: 40%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    font-size:12px;
    float:right;
} 
#TestContainer {
    border: solid 1px red;  
    width: 40%;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;   
    float:left;
    cursor:default;
} 
ul{
    list-style-type: none;  
    text-align: left;   
    padding-left: 15px; 
    padding-top: 3px;
} 
li{
    padding-bottom: 0px;    
    padding-top: 1px;
    display:inline;
}
img {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-right: 0px ;  
  margin-right: 0px ;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
} 

img .testcat {

} 
span {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 5px ;  
  padding-right: 5px ;   
  color: black;
  font-size:15px;
}
.nochild {
    font-size:10px;
}
.droppable-below {
   border-bottom: 2px solid blue; 
   margin-top: 0px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;   
}
.droppable-in {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: yellow;
}
/*
.TestContainer, .TestContainer ul, .TestContainer li {
     position: relative;
}
.TestContainer ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 12px;
}
.TestContainer li::before, .TestContainer li::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -12px;
}
.TestContainer li::before {
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    top: 5px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
.TestContainer li::after { 
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
    height: 170%;
    width: 0px;
    top: -8px;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
.TestContainer ul > li:last-child::after {
    height: 8px;
} */
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="mainApp">
        <div ng-controller="TreeController">                    
             <div id="TestContainer" class="TestContainer">
             <collection collection='testdata'></collection>             
             </div>          
        </div>              
    </div>
</body>
<script>    
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", [])
mainApp.directive('collection', function () {       
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {collection: '='},
        template: "<ul><member ng-repeat='member in collection' member='member'></member></ul>"         
    }
})

mainApp.directive('member', function ($compile) {
    var NewChild = "<li><img class=opcl ng-src={{PlusMinusImage}} ng-click=ShowHideFunc()></img><img class=testcat ng-src={{C15Image}}></img><span ng-click=ShowDetailsFunc()>{{member.TagName}}</span></li>";      
    var linkerfunc = function(scope, element, attrs) {  
                    var collectionSt = '<collection collection="member.children"></collection>';
                    $compile(collectionSt)(scope, function(cloned, scope)   {                                           
                        //element.css("background-color", "#ff00ff");                           
                        if (scope.member.children.length === 0){
                        $(element[0]).children().first().remove()
                        $(element[0]).addClass("child");                        
                        } else 
                        {
                        $(element[0]).addClass("parent");                       
                        }
                        element.attr('xml-path', scope.member.TagPath);                         
                        element.append(cloned);                         
                     });                    
                    scope.ShowHideFunc = function() {                   
                        scope.ShowHideCtrlFunc(element,event);
                        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                      };
    }   
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {member: '=', ShowHideCtrlFunc : '&', ShowDetailsCtrlFunc : '&'},
        template: NewChild,     
        controller: 'TreeController',
        link: linkerfunc        
    }
})
mainApp.controller('TreeController', function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.testdata = [{"TagName":"LandXML","TagPath":">MyRootNode>ChildItems>LandXML","children":[{"TagName":"Units","TagPath":">MyRootNode>ChildItems>ChildItems[1]>Units","children":[{"TagName":"Imperial","TagPath":">MyRootNode>ChildItems>ChildItems[1]>ChildItems[1]>Imperial","children":[]},{"TagName":"Project","TagPath":">MyRootNode>ChildItems>ChildItems[1]>Project","children":[]},{"TagName":"Application","TagPath":">MyRootNode>ChildItems>ChildItems[1]>Application","children":[{"TagName":"Author","TagPath":">MyRootNode>ChildItems>ChildItems[1]>ChildItems[2]>Author","children":[]},{"TagName":"Alignments","TagPath":">MyRootNode>ChildItems>ChildItems[1]>Alignments","children":[]},{"TagName":"Roadways","TagPath":">MyRootNode>ChildItems>ChildItems[1]>Roadways","children":[{"TagName":"Roadway1","TagPath":">MyRootNode>ChildItems>ChildItems[1]>ChildItems[3]>Roadway[1]","children":[]},{"TagName":"Roadway2","TagPath":">MyRootNode>ChildItems>ChildItems[1]>ChildItems[3]>Roadway[2]","children":[]},{"TagName":"Roadway3","TagPath":">MyRootNode>ChildItems>ChildItems[1]>ChildItems[3]>Roadway[3]","children":[]},{"TagName":"Roadway4","TagPath":">MyRootNode>ChildItems>ChildItems[1]>ChildItems[3]>Roadway[4]","children":[]},{"TagName":"Roadway5","TagPath":">MyRootNode>ChildItems>ChildItems[1]>ChildItems[3]>Roadway[5]","children":[]}]}]}]}]},{"TagName":"Surfaces","TagPath":">MyRootNode>ChildItems>Surfaces","children":[{"TagName":"Surface1","TagPath":">MyRootNode>ChildItems>ChildItems[2]>Surface1","children":[]},{"TagName":"Surface2","TagPath":">MyRootNode>ChildItems>ChildItems[2]>Surface2","children":[]}]}]
    $scope.PlusMinusImage = '../Images/Plus15.png';
    $scope.C15Image = '../Images/C15.png' ;

    $scope.ShowHideCtrlFunc = function(element,event) {
            //console.log("in function ShowHideCtrlFunc");                      
            if ($scope.PlusMinusImage === '../Images/Plus15.png') {
                $scope.PlusMinusImage = '../Images/Minus15.png';
            } else {
                $scope.PlusMinusImage = '../Images/Plus15.png';
            }
            $(element).children().last().toggle();          
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
      };    
    makedraggable() 
});
function makedraggable() {
    var myimg = $('<img/>').attr({
                        src:"images/whitebriefcase4.png"
                        })
    $("li").draggable({ 
                    containment: '#TestContainer',
                    cursorAt: { top: -0, left: -15 },                               
                    helper: function() {
                            return $("<div></div>").append(myimg);
                            },                          
                    revert: "invalid",
                    drag: function(event,ui) {
                                $(this).find('span').first().css({"font-weight": "bold", "background-color": "lightblue"});                             
                            },
                    stop: function(){
                            $(this).find('span').first().css({"font-weight": "normal", "background-color": "white"});
                         },                     
                    drop: function (event){
                                console.log("I am dragged and dropped")
                                //event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                                }
                });

    $('.parent').droppable({
        greedy: true,
        hoverClass: "droppable-in", //, border: 5px solid red;                  
        /*
        over: function() {
            //$(this).children().first().next().css({"border": "1px solid black", "background-color": "yellow"})
            $(this).css({"border": "1px solid black", "background-color": "yellow"})
            //console.log($(this).parent());    
        },
        out: function() {
            $(this).css({"border": "none", "background-color": "white"})
        }, */
        drop: function(event, ui) { 
            //console.log($(ui.draggable).text());
            //console.log($(this).next());      
            $(this).next().append($(ui.draggable));
            $(this).css({"border": "none", "background-color": "white"})
        }
    });

}; 
</script>   
</html>
```

Please help

Comment: You should break this down into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You used `droppable-in` class in `hoverClass` like below:

```
 $('.parent').droppable({
        greedy: true,
        hoverClass: "droppable-in", 
        ...
    });
```

This class defined as follows and causes `yellow` background.

```
.droppable-in {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

You can comment code below and test drop again.

```
// hoverClass: "droppable-in",
```